# Pagination in Twilio Java SDK returns only the first page

Tags: scala, twilio, twilio-api

I need to list all of the available for buying numbers by a certain phone number prefix, with the following approach:

```
def queryLocal(numberToBuy: NumberToBuy)
             (implicit client: TwilioRestClient, ec: ExecutionContext): List[String] ={

  val cc = numberToBuy.countryCode
  val prefix = numberToBuy.numberPrefix.tail
  val reader: LocalReader = Local.reader(cc).setVoiceEnabled(true).setContains(prefix)

  @tailrec def inner(acc: List[String], currentPage: Page[Local]): List[String] = {
    if (currentPage.hasNextPage){
      val nextPage = reader.nextPage(currentPage)
      val newAcc = nextPage.getRecords.asScala.toList.map(_.getPhoneNumber.toString) ++ acc

      inner(newAcc, nextPage)
    } else {
      acc
    }
  }

  val page: Page[Local] = reader.firstPage(client)

  inner(page.getRecords.asScala.toList.map(_.getPhoneNumber.toString), page)
}
```

but it always returns only the first page (30 records) because `hasNextPage` is always false even though more than 30 numbers is available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe that this is because there isn't pagination information returned with the available phone numbers resource, so you can't show all of the available phone numbers in the catalog.

Instead, if you want to choose a different number that is not available in the first list you return, just make the request to the list resource again and different numbers will be returned.